# css missing margin after jquery append

Tags: jquery, append

I have used jQuery's `.append()` function to create a set of divs which wrap some `<input />` and `<span>`, but after I create the divs, it missing the margin between `<input>` tag,just as the following picture:

image with margin:
[image]

image without margin(jquery create):
[image]

the html code:

```
<div class="controls">
    <input type="text" class="span3" name="name" placeholder="规格名称" />
    <input type="text" class="span3" name="name" placeholder="商品价格" />
    <input type="text" class="span3" name="name" placeholder="商品原价" />
    <input type="text" class="span2" name="name" placeholder="商品库存" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span id="good_sku_add" class="icon-plus"></span>
</div>
```

the jquery code:

```
$('#good_sku_add').click(function(){
    html = '';
    html += '<div class="controls">';
    html += '<input type="text" class="span3" name="name" placeholder="规格名称" />';
    html += '<input type="text" class="span3" name="name" placeholder="商品价格" />';
    html += '<input type="text" class="span3" name="name" placeholder="商品原价" />';
    html += '<input type="text" class="span2" name="name" placeholder="商品库存" />';
    html += '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    html += '<span id="good_sku_add" class="icon-plus"></span>';
    html += '</div>';

    $(this).parent().after(html);
    $(this).parent().parent().trigger('create');
  })
```

I search some doc on stackoverflow and google,but it can't work,can anyone give me some idea?

Comment: Why are you not using padding/margins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the margin that's missing, what's missing is just a space between your inputs (inline elements are sensitive to white space). Just add one in at the end of each line of your input code:

```
html += '<input type="text" class="span3" name="name" placeholder="规格名称" /> ';
                                                                              ^
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/187ugya5/)**

Comment: thanks,you are right!but how this work?why the white space use the html entity "&nbsp;"?

Comment: I don't understand your comment about &nbsp;

Comment: I mean in html, if I want to display a white space,we should use '&nbsp;' not just type  the "white space" key in the keyboard? sorry for my bad english..

Comment: Well they're not exactly equivalent. `&nbsp;` is a non-breaking space which is usually used between words and not allow a break between them.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing spaces between the `<input />` tags in the dynamically created version.

E.g., try this:

```
html = '';
html += '<div class="controls"> ';
html += '<input type="text" class="span3" name="name" placeholder="规格名称" /> ';
html += '<input type="text" class="span3" name="name" placeholder="商品价格" /> ';
html += '<input type="text" class="span3" name="name" placeholder="商品原价" /> ';
html += '<input type="text" class="span2" name="name" placeholder="商品库存" /> ';
html += '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
html += '<span id="good_sku_add" class="icon-plus"></span>';
html += '</div>';
```

Explanation:

In the HTML version, the leading whitespace (indentation) before the `<intput />` tags is collapsed to a single whitespace character when rendered.  In your HTML version, due to the string concatenation approach, there's no whitespace at all between the tags.

A (subjectively) cleaner approach might be to try this:

```
var html = [
    '<div class="controls">',
    '<input type="text" class="span3" name="name" placeholder="规格名称" />',
    '<input type="text" class="span3" name="name" placeholder="商品价格" />',
    '<input type="text" class="span3" name="name" placeholder="商品原价" />',
    '<input type="text" class="span2" name="name" placeholder="商品库存" />',
    '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;',
    '<span id="good_sku_add" class="icon-plus"></span>',
    '</div>'
].join(' ');
```